# Error while creating a new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed the latest ruby 2.6 and rails 5.2.
then i tried creating a new app but i am stuck with an error i cant figure out.

```
current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20190212-2716-9s9m2t.rb extconf.rb checking for sqlite3.h...
no sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/
first.
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: The error message says _`sqlite3.h` is missing. Install SQLite3 from [http://www.sqlite.org/](http://www.sqlite.org/) first._ Did you follow that instruction? Is SQLite itself (no the gem that depends on it) installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue on Linux version.  The error presented differently though (error during a request from browser after calling `rails server`).  It seems, in my case, the 1.4.0 version is not compatible.  Try putting this in your Gemfile and rerunning `bundle install`: `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'`

Comment: Here the reason not in version